# Python Twisted - Server communication

Tags: python, twisted

I'm having a bizarre issue. Basically, the problem I have right now is dealing with two different LineReceiver servers that are connected to each other. Essentially, if I were to input something into server A, then I want some output to appear in server B. And I would like to do this vice versa. I am running two servers on two different source files (also running them on different processes via & shellscript) ServerA.py and ServerB.py where the ports are (12650 and 12651) respectively. I am also connecting to each server using telnet.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class ServerA(LineReceiver);
   def connectionMade(self):
      self.transport.write("Is Server A\n")
   def dataReceived(self, data):
      self.sendLine(data)
   def lineReceived(self, line):
      self.transport.write(line)

def main():
   client = protocol.ClientFactory()
   client.protocol = ServerA
   reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 12650, client)

   server = protocol.ServerFactory()
   server.protocol = ServerA
   reactor.listenTCP(12651, server)

   reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

My issue is the use of sendLine. When I try to do a sendLine call from serverA with some arbitrary string, serverA ends up spitting out the exact string instead of sending it down the connection which was done in main(). Exactly why is this happening? I've been looking around and tried each solution I came across and I can't seem to get it to work properly. The bizarre thing is my friend is essentially doing the same thing and he gets some working results but this is the simplest program I could think of to try to figure out the cause for this strange phenomenon.

In any case, the gist is, I'm expecting to get the input I put into serverA to appear in serverB.

Note: Server A and Server B have the exact same source code save for the class names and ports.

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden `dataReceived`.  That means that `lineReceived` will never be called, because it is `LineReceiver`'s `dataReceived` implementation that eventually calls `lineReceived`, and you're never calling up to it.

You should only need to override `lineReceived` and then things should work as you expect.

Comment: Hey, I tried removing the overridden dataReceived but it still has the same behavior. Server B isn't receiving anything from server A with sendLine.

Comment: I think I found the solution. I had to keep track of what's connecting to the server such as clients = [] and then appending an instance of the client to that list every time a connection is made. I'm guessing my above code was actually just sending the data to itself.